# recv message and write to file

Tags: erlang

I have made a server here which receives messages from the terminal. What I want to do is when the server receives the messages from the terminal it should write it into a file. But I dont know how I should do this. I thought of writing the file methods `file:open`, `file:write` in the receive functions but it didnt work out as I thought.

```
-module(tcp).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3, start/0, stop/0, connect/0, send/1, recv/0]).

-export([start_link/0]).

%% =============================================================================
%% EXPORTED GEN_SERVER CALLBACKS
%% =============================================================================

init([]) -> {ok, {}}.

handle_call({send, Packet}, _From, State) ->
    gen_tcp:send(State, Packet),
    io:format("Send Working\n"),
    {reply, ok, State};

handle_call(recv, _From, State) ->
     Message = gen_tcp:recv(State, 0),
    io:format("~w~n", [Message]),
    {reply, Message, State}.

handle_cast(connect, _) ->
    case gen_tcp:listen(6888, [binary]) of
    {ok, LSocket}->
        io:format("~w~n", [LSocket]),
        case gen_tcp:accept(LSocket) of 
        {ok, Socket} ->
            inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, false}]),
            io:format("accepted\n"),
            {noreply, Socket};
        Other ->
            error_logger:error_report(["An error occurred which is",Other,"in line",?LINE,"of module",?MODULE])

        end;
    {error, Reason} ->
        error_logger:error_report("An error occurred", Reason, [?LINE,?MODULE])
    end;

handle_cast(stop, State) -> {stop, normal, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) -> {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) -> ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) -> {ok, State}.


%% =============================================================================
%% EXPORTED CONVENIENCE FUNCTIONS TO START AND STOP THE SERVER
%% =============================================================================

start() ->
    case gen_server:start({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []) of
        {ok, Pid} ->
            Pid;
        Reason ->
            error_logger:error_report("An error occurred", Reason, [?LINE,?MODULE])
    end.

stop() ->
    case gen_server:cast(?MODULE, stop) of
        ok ->
            ok;
        _ ->
            {error, stop_error}
    end.


%% =============================================================================
%% PUBLIC API FUNCTIONS
%% =============================================================================

connect() -> gen_server:cast(?MODULE, connect).

send(Packet) -> gen_server:call(?MODULE, {send, Packet}).

recv() -> gen_server:call(?MODULE, recv).

write_file(Filename) ->
    {ok, IoDevice} = file:open(test.txt, [write, append]),
    ok.

start_link() -> gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).


%% =============================================================================
%% LOCAL FUNCTIONS
%% =============================================================================
```

---

I did as you suggested and implemented it as a `handle_call` but when i run i get an error,

> function handle_call/3 already defined error

I quite dont understand why I get this error since i have 3 arguments for the handle_call and it should work.

```
handle_call(write_file, Filename, S) ->
    {ok, File} = file:open(Filename, [append]),
    ok = file:write(File, S),
    ok = file:close(File).
```

My API Function

```
write_file() -> gen_server:call(?MODULE, write_file).
```

Comment: Wellcome to SO, please leave away the "hellos" and "thanks" and care about typography. It increases the probability of good answers and helps the future readers of you Question.

Answer (score 3):

Your handle call doesn't work because you have two definitions of it. You have written:

```
 handle_call(...) ->
   do_something.

 handle_call(M, F, S) ->
   do_some_other_thing.
```

You should make them into the same function, by changing:

```
   do_something.
```

into:

```
   do_something;
handle_call(M, F, S) ->
   do_some_other_thing.
```

Answer (score 2):

`write_file` should do something like:

```
write_file(Fname, S) ->
    ok = file:write_file(Fname, S, [append]).
```

or

```
write_file(Fname, S) ->
    {ok, File} = file:open(Fname, [append]),
    ok = file:write(File, S),
    ok = file:close(File).
```